# Optimize a Java code with maps and lambda expresions

Tags: java, optimization, java-8

I have this code, it gets data for a "rate" if any of these parameters don't have the adequate values I have to change the value from parameter to a string "ALL", so what is de best way? my actual code is this:

```
Map<String, List<Example>> exampleMap= cacheExampleData.getExample();
BigDecimal rate = exampleMap
    .get(RequestDto.getCustomer() == null ? "ALL" : RequestDto.getCustomerSubsegment())
    .stream().filter(x -> x.getSaleChannel().equalsIgnoreCase(RequestDto.getChannelId()))
    .filter(x -> x.getFlowName().equalsIgnoreCase(flowName))
    .filter(x -> x.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(RequestDto.getCustomerSegment()))
    .map(Example::getRate).findFirst().orElse(null);

if (rate == null && RequestDto.getCustomerSubsegment() != null) {
     rate = exampleMap
    .get(Constant.All)
    .stream().filter(x -> x.getSaleChannel().equalsIgnoreCase(RequestDto.getChannelId()))
    .filter(x -> x.getFlowName().equalsIgnoreCase(flowName))
    .filter(x -> x.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(RequestDto.getCustomerSegment()))
    .map(Example::getRate).findFirst().orElse(null);
 }

if (rate == null) {
     rate = exampleMap
    .get(Constant.All)
    .stream().filter(x -> x.getSaleChannel().equalsIgnoreCase(Constant.All)
    .filter(x -> x.getFlowName().equalsIgnoreCase(flowName))
    .filter(x -> x.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(RequestDto.getCustomerSegment()))
    .map(Example::getRate).findFirst().orElse(null);
 }

.
.
.
if (rate == null) {
     Do the same but with ALL in the first and second...X element
 }
```

Comment: can you show me the cases of as is and to be

Comment: I just edited it with the first 2 cases, the next cases are similar, putting the Constat.All